# which 'on' method is called when the trackball's 'Select' button is pressed?

Tags: android, event-handling, trackball

which 'on' event is invoked when the user selects a ListView item by pressing the trackball button?
i trapped onKeyDown, onTouchEvent, onTrackballEvent
but it's none of those...
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a "click" and triggers your `OnItemClickListener` (or `onListItemClick()` if you are implementing a `ListActivity`).